# Tell scipy.optimize.minimize to fail

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimize

I'm using scipy.optimize.minimize for unrestricted optimization of an objective function which receives a couple of parameters and runs a complex numerical simulation based on these parameters. This simulation does not always converge in which case I make the objective function return inf, in some cases, in others NaN.

I thought that this hack would prevent the minimization from converging anywhere near a set of parameters that makes the simulation diverge. Instead, I encountered a case where the simulation won't even converge for the starting set of parameters but instead of failing, the optimization terminates "successfully" with 0 iterations. It doesn't seem to care about the objective function returning inf.

Is there a way to tell scipy.optimize.minimize to fail, e.g. by raising some sort of exception. While in this case it's obvious that the optimization didn't terminate successfully - because of 0 iterations and the fact that I know the optimal result - at some point I want to run problems that I don't know the solution for and I need to rely on minimize to tell me if shit hit the fan. If returning lots of nans and infs doesn't "break" the algorithm I guess I'll have to do it by brute force.

---

Here is an example of what the almost-iteration looks like.
The function - a function of two variables - is called 4 times over all:
**1)** at the starting point -> simulation diverges, f(x) = inf
**2)** at a point 1e-5 to the right (gradient approximation) -> simulation diverges, f(x) = inf
**3)** at a point 1e-5 higher (grad. appr.) -> simulation converges, f(x) = some finite value
**4)** once more at the starting point -> simulation diverges, f(x) = inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options I can think of:

- opt for constrained optimization
- modify your objective function to diverge whenever your numerical simulation does not converge. Basically this means returning a large value, large compared to a 'normal' value, which depends on your problem at hand. `minimize` will then try to optimize going in another direction

I am however a bit surprised that `minimize` does not understand `inf` as a large value, and does not try to look for a solution in another direction. Could it be that it returns with 0 iterations only when your objective function returns `nan`? You could try debugging the issue by printing the value just before the `return` statement in your objective function.

Comment: I tried this and apparently NaN isn't even ever an issue. I edited the question to include a summary of the 0th iteration.  

The problem with constrained optimization would be that I would have to run the simulation more often, as part of the objective function and as part of the constraint function, which would have to be a binary-valued one. Sounds extremely messy and inefficient.

Comment: From the above, your initial guess is not a valid point, and `fmin` refuses to continue, mainly because the local gradient is not finite, i.e. at least a component of it is not finite. Can you craft/do you know a valid guess for the starting point?

Comment: I can't seem to find an initial guess that is valid and still reproduces the problem. Assuming that `fmin` will never choose an invalid point in any further iteration (which seems to be a justified assumption), this pretty much solves my problem. Thanks!