# Additionally restricting scipy's root solver

Tags: python, scipy, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations using `scipy.optimize.root()`

One of the equations contains a power like `x[5]**epsilon`, where epsilon is a parameter. For `epsilon=1` I manage to find the roots, but for any different epsilon around `1`, I cannot. I get `NaN` somewhere along the process, which I presume comes from the solver *trying out* negative values and getting `NaN` for that.

Is there any way to furthermore restrict the solver, as in telling him `x[5] >= 0` or similar? I know that scipy's minimization tools can use these boundaries, but I fail to find anything like that in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html#module-scipy.optimize.nonlin) for `root`.

Comment: A fast workaround is something like `if x[5]<0: return ones_like(x)*inf`. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659698/tell-scipy-optimize-minimize-to-fail/23659957#23659957)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `x[5]**epsilon`, replace it with `np.exp(x[5])**epsilon` in your target function. Then `x[5]` can be any value between `-inf` and `+inf` and `np.exp(x[5])` will always be positive.

Stay away from `abs(x[5])` or similar other transformations that might make the derivative non-continuous.